# Is there a simple awk/sed way to print list in YAML file?

Tags: awk, sed, yaml

I'm looking for an optimized way to print a particular list in a YAML file using sed or/and awk.
For example, in the below sample yaml file, how do I get the list of Fruits alone printed on screen,say, comma separated?

## Input File: boston_mart.yaml

What I am able to acheive using awk is to print after "Fruits:" but I also want another contition to print only if "-" is in front of the words. That is where I am stuck. Any help or pointers will be very helpful.

```
## YAML
Market: open
Season: fall
Fruits:
- apple
- orange
- banana
- grapes
Vendors: 7
Buyers: 5
Vegetables:
- tomato
- carrot
- broccoli
Location: Boston
```

## Output

```
apple
orange
banana
grapes
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '$1 == "-"{ if (key == "Fruits:") print $NF; next } {key=$1}' file
apple
orange
banana
grapes
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining how "key" is used in the two places?

Comment: You're welcome. This forum is for helping people with **their** code but I posted this to give you an opportunity to figure out how it works instead since you didn't post any code. So, please read the awk man pages, add some prints, google or do whatever you have to do to try to figure it out for  yourself and THEN feel free to ask any specific questions (but it is extremely common, trivial code).

Comment: `key` is just the name of a variable here; you could call it `section` instead if that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^Fruits:/,/^[^-]/{//b; s/^- //p}' -- data
```

where:

- `-n` by default don't echo input
- `/…/,/…/` handle range of lines from 'Fruits:' to one not starting with '-' (incl. EOF)
- `//b` skip line if last regex matched (i.e. range bounds)
- otherwise strip dash and print line

Output:

```
apple
orange
banana
grapes
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/:/h;G;s/^- (.*)\nFruits:/\1/p' file
```

Make a copy of the key.

Append the copy to each line.

If a line starts `-` and contains the required key, print its value.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1~/:/{key=$1}   key~/Fruits:/&&$1=="-"{print $2} ' file
```

**Output:**
apple
orange
banana
grapes