# Grep everything after pattern whose # of lines are inconsistent

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I'm trying to find a way to grep out a specific text out of a bunch of similar files. Example:

```
-
Blah1: stuff
Blah2: stuff
Blah3:
 - bingo
 - this
 - is
 - what im looking for
Blah4: stuff
-
Blah1: stuff
Blah2: stuff
Blah3:
 - bingo this is
 - what im looking for
Blah4: stuff
```

However the "bingo this is what I'm looking for" isn't always 4 lines and is sometimes 2 or 15 lines following same pattern but always starts with a new line and proceeded by `-` and Blah3 is always Blah3

I need a way of getting an output that shows just

```
Blah3:
- Bingo
- this
- is
- what im looking for
Blah3:
- bingo this is
- what im looking for
```

Tried using -A on `grep` but the number of lines that come sfter Blah3: are inconsistent and tried using quite a bit of regex with grep but still can't get the output I'm lookikg for

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Input looks like yaml. I would try python on it.

Comment: See [is-there-a-simple-awk-sed-way-to-print-list-in-yaml-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66188107/is-there-a-simple-awk-sed-way-to-print-list-in-yaml-file).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\S\+:/h;G;/^Blah3:/MP;d' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the `-n` option.

Copy any key to the hold space.

Append the hold space to each line.

If the required key is present, print the first line in the pattern space.

N.B. The `M` flag on a regexp allows the `^` to match at the beginning of a line.

Alternative:

```
sed -n '/^Blah3:/{:a;p;n;/^ -/ba}' file
```