# Extract string following pattern (grep)

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am trying to learn how to use grep.
I have a file that list my python packages as follow:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - numpy=1.21.1=py39h6635163_0
  - pyinstaller=4.2=py39h4dafc3f_1
  - ...
```

I am only interested what comes after "dependancies".
I am trying, using bash grep/sed/awk whatever basic linux tool, to iterate in all those lines, to save in one variable the python package and in another variable the version (I dont care about what is after the last =) and to call a function.

Example for the first line:

```
$ > echo $1 $2
numpy 1.21.1
```

Thans you for your help

Comment: don't be lazy, provide the loop and declare the function at least

Comment: - Similar question here in stackoverflow.com: "Is there a simple awk/sed way to print list in YAML file?"  where you can get the Ed Morton's answer using `awk`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66188243/14259465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `awk`:

```
awk '$1 == "-"{ if (key == "dependencies:") print $NF; next } {key=$1}' file
numpy=1.21.1=py39h6635163_0
pyinstaller=4.2=py39h4dafc3f_1
...
```

Ed Morton's code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66188243/14259465

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
grep -oP "\w+=[\d.]+" test.txt | while IFS="=" read -r P V; do
    export A=$P
    export B=$V
done
```

Where test.txt is:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - numpy=1.21.1=py39h6635163_0
  - pyinstaller=4.2=py39h4dafc3f_1
  - ...
```

And $A is the package name and $B is version

Comment: Rather than separately call `cut` on each value in a subprocess, use `while IFS='=' read -r A B _; do`

Comment: Probably note that `grep -P` is nonstandard; but it's not hard to refactor the regex into a bog-standard POSIX one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have YAML input, the proper soulution is to use a YAML tool like `yq`.

```sh
yq eval '.dependencies[]' file.yaml |
while IFS='=' read -r package version _; do
    echo Package: "$package"
    echo Version: "$version"
done
```

If you are unable to install `yq`, maybe try Awk; but understand that this is brittle, and makes assumptions about your YAML formatting.

```sh
awk '/dependencies:/ { p=1; next }
    p { if ($1 == "-") {
        split($2, fields, "=")
        print fields[1], fields[2]
      } else p=0 }' file.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be understood in two different ways:

- I would like `grep` in order to avoid needing a loop.
- I know I need to write a loop, but I don't know how to use `grep` in a loop.

It is correct that `grep` can avoid loops, like in this example:

File1.txt:

```
test1
test2
something_else
```

Mission: loop through the file and give every entry, starting with "test".

Solution:

```
grep "test" File1.txt
```

=> no loop needed, because `grep` is capable of finding all results **where** a pattern is found.

However, I don't think `grep` has an option stating "Give all results **once** a pattern is found.", so here you cannot avoid writing a loop using `grep`.